# Undefined Reference for all functions in c++

Tags: c++, class, undefined-reference

I found a lot of questions regarding these errors but nothing has helped me. Here are my makefile, main function file, and class file used in the main. I know it is a linking problem but cannot find my error. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:Sorry...here is the error message. I am pretty stressed out and forgot to include it.

```
prog1.o: In function `main':
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `Quash::Quash()'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `Quash::contains(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `Quash::contains(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `Quash::insert(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `Quash::contains(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `Quash::contains(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `Quash::empty()'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `Quash::root()'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `Quash::contains(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `Quash::deleteMin()'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `Quash::deleteNum(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `Quash::deleteNum(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x36d): undefined reference to `Quash::contains(int)'
prog1.cpp:(.text+0x3bd): undefined reference to `Quash::print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Makefile:

```
all: prog1



prog1: Quash.o prog1.o

        g++ *.o -o prog1



prog1.o: prog1.cpp

        g++ -c prog1.cpp



Quash.o: Quash.h Quash.cpp Hashtable.o Minheap.o Node.o

        g++ -c Quash.cpp



Hashtable.o: Hashtable.h Hashtable.cpp

        g++ -c Hashtable.cpp



Minheap.o: Minheap.h Minheap.cpp

        g++ -c Minheap.cpp



Node.o: Node.h Node.cpp

        g++ -c Node.cpp



clean:

        rm -f *.o

        rm -f prog1
```

prog1.cpp:

```
#include "Quash.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Quash* theQuash = new Quash();

  while(!cin.eof())
  {
    string cmd;
    cin >> cmd;

    if(cmd.compare("insert") == 0)
    {
      int i;
      cin >> i;

      if(theQuash->contains(i) != 0)
      {
        cout << "item already present, new count = " << theQuash->contains(i) << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        if(theQuash->insert(i))
        {
          cout << "item successfully inserted, count = 1" << endl;
        }
      }
    }
    else if(cmd.compare("lookup") == 0)
    {
      int i;
      cin >> i;

      if(theQuash->contains(i) != 0)
      {
        cout << "item found, count = " << theQuash->contains(i) << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "item not found" << endl;
      }
    }
    else if(cmd.compare("deleteMin") == 0)
    {
      if(theQuash->empty())
      {
        cout << "min item not present since table is empty" << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        int i = theQuash->root(), retVal = theQuash->contains(i);
        if(retVal == 1)
        {
          theQuash->deleteMin();
          cout << "min item " << i << " successfully deleted" << endl;
        }
        else if(retVal > 1)
        {
          int newCount = theQuash->deleteNum(i);
          cout << "min item = " << i << ", count decremented, new count = " << newCount << endl;
        }
      }
    }
    else if(cmd.compare("delete") == 0)
    {
      int i;
      cin >> i;

      int retVal = theQuash->deleteNum(i);
      if(retVal == 1)
      {
        cout << "item successfully deleted" << endl;
      }
      else if(retVal == 2)
      {
        cout << "item not present in the table" << endl;
      }
      else if(retVal == 0)
      {
        cout << "item count decremented, new count = " << theQuash->contains(i) << endl;
      }
    }
    else if(cmd.compare("print") == 0)
    {
      theQuash->print();
    }
  }
}
```

Quash.h

```
#ifndef QUASH_H
#define QUASH_H

#include "Hashtable.h"
#include "Minheap.h"


class Quash{


 private:
  Minheap heap;
  Hashtable hash;

 public: 
  Quash();
  ~Quash();
  int root();
  bool empty();
  bool insert(int i);
  bool lookup(int i);
  bool deleteMin();
  int deleteNum(int i);
  void print();
  int contains(int i);


};
#endif
```

Quash.cpp:

```
#include "Hashtable.h"
#include "Minheap.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Quash
{
private:
  Minheap* heap;
  Hashtable* hash;

public:

  Quash()
  {
    heap = new Minheap();
    hash = new Hashtable();
  }

  ~Quash()
  {
    delete heap;
    delete hash;
  }

  int root()
  {
    return heap->getRoot();
  }

  bool empty()
  {
    if(heap->getNumElements() == 0)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  bool insert(int i)
  {
    Node* temp = new Node(i);
    if(heap->insert(temp) && hash->insert(*temp))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      delete temp;
      return false;
    }
  }

  bool deleteMin()
  {
    return false;
  }

  int deleteNum(int i)
  {
    Node* temp = new Node(i);
    int retVal = hash->deleteNode(*temp);
    /*TODO
      HEAP DELETION
    */
    delete temp;
    return retVal;
  }
  void print()
  {
    heap->print();
    return;
  }
  int contains(int i) // lookup(i) in assignment
  {
    Node* temp = new Node(i);
    int retVal = hash->lookup(*temp);
    delete temp;
    if(retVal == 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      return retVal;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Just a few things here - first, for future reference, please split apart your makefile, headers, source files, etc. and clearly label each. This will make it easier for us to read your code and find issues. Second - instead of telling us you're getting "undefined reference" errors for all your functions, please copy and paste the exact error log you're getting, and wrap it in code tags. This will make it easier for us to find your exact problem and problem location. Third - please don't use `using namespace std;` in header files. Fourth - I suggest formatting your code.

Comment: I find it mind boggling that so many people who ask questions on stackoverflow about compiler or linker errors don't bother to post the actual error message.  Copy/paste has existed on computers for more than 20 years. I think this should be grounds for an automatic close and delete.

Comment: Sorry I am very stressed about this error and forgot to post the error message. It is my first post, please forgive me...?

Comment: @maxsorenson: sorry for my rant; I usually try to point out that the error message(s) should be included and give the OP a chance to edit it in.  I'm sorry that I didn't give you that opportunity.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks and sorry for the formatting errors I thought I wrapped all the code in separate code blocks I guess since I didn't put anything in between it just added them all together. Hopefully I can get the errors fixed though!

Comment: @maxsorenson: I think the file you've labelled as `Quash.cpp` is really `prog1.cpp` because the linker says that `main()` is in `prog1.o`.

Comment: I honestly don't even remember naming them :/ I must really be out of it

Comment: @maxsorenson I actually edited your post to insert the names for clarity's sake, taking my best guess based on your #includes. I apologize if I was incorrect about one; feel free to re-edit your post to fix whatever needs to be fixed.

Comment: @computerfreaker already did. Thanks for the effort though! I should have had it done to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the definition (in `Quash.h`) from the implementation (in `Quash.cpp`)

`Quash.h`

```
#ifndef QUASH_H_
#define QUASH_H_ // protect against multiple include

class Quash
{
    Quash(); // constructor, declare only the prototype
    // similarly for the rest of the methods
};
#endif
```

`Quash.cpp`

```
#include "Quash.h"
#include "Hashtable.h"
#include "Minheap.h"

// DO NOT redefine your class here, only implement its methods

Quash::Quash()
{
   // now implement the constructor
   heap = new Minheap();
   hash = new Hashtable();
};

Quash::~Quash()
{
    // and the destructor
    delete heap;
    delete hash;
}
// do the same for the rest of the methods
```

And, in `main.cpp`, `#include "Quash.h"`

Comment: They are implemented in the .cpp file, someone edited my code incorectly, let me fix the names

Comment: No, `Quash` class implements the functions in the header.

Comment: I haven't provided my Quash.h file, I can add if necessary?

Comment: The cleanest way to do it is to declare the class and its methods' prototype in a header file, then implement the methods in a .cpp file. Not sure how you're doing it. The compiler has to know the signature of all methods. For example, declare `class Foo{ Foo(); };` in the header Foo.h, then implement it in Foo.cpp as `#include "Foo.h" \\newline  Foo::Foo(){...};` That is, declare only the signature of the methods in the header file, and implement them in the .cpp. Or, implement everything in the header and don't forget to include the header in the main program.

Comment: So, you need `Quash.h`, and include it in main.cpp.

Comment: I have just added my Quash.h file to the post, and it was already included in the prog1.cpp file.

Comment: You are not implementing the Quash correctly in `Quash.cpp`. See my updated answer. You should NOT redefine the class, just implement its methods inside the `Quash.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's quite a bit of confusion due to some of the file contents being mislabeled in the first few edits of the question.  Based on what's been posted and the error messages by thinker, it looks like what is happening is that you have two separate declarations of `class Queue` (one in `Queue.h` and another separate one in `Queue.cpp` that has nothing but inline functions that never get used as far as the compiler sees).

You should do one of the following:

- move the `class Quash` declaration that's in `Quash.cpp` into the `Quash.h` header so the functions will be inline and available to all clients of `class Quash`
- change `Quash.cpp` so that it has a `#include "Quash.h` to get the declaration of `class Quash` and simply implements the functions.  They would end up looking like:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Hashtable.h"
  #include "Minheap.h"

  #include "Quash.h"

  // note: there is no class Quash { ... } surrounding these functions -
  //       the class has already been declared in Quash.h, the .cpp file 
  //       only contains the function defintions for any functions that 
  //       are not defined inline in the .h file  (and definitions of 
  //       static data members)

  Quash::Quash()
  {
      heap = new Minheap();
      hash = new Hashtable();
  }

  Quash::~Quash()
  {
      delete heap;
      delete hash;
  }

  // etc for each of the functions delcared (but not inline-defined) in `Quash.h`
  ```

Comment: I am fixing my .cpp implementations to remove the class {} and use Quash:: qualifiers, do I include the private/public member variables again in the .cpp?

Comment: @maxsorenson: only if they are static.

Comment: It seems to be compiling/linking now, but I am getting no results when running the program with./prog1

Comment: It might be time to learn some `gdb`: add a `-g` option to the `g++` commands in the makefile then do `gdb ./prog1`.  gdb's `start` command will get you to `main()` then `next` or `step` commands will walk through the program. `next ` will 'jump' over function calls, while `step` will step into them (read the gdb docs for details).  Alternatively, add `cout << "reached location 1" << end;` lines at strategic places in your program (change the location number appropriately, and add any variables you want to know the value of at that point). That's known as 'printf debugging'.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Turns out the program was running I just was expecting an output terminal for the user to type into.

Answer (score 1):

In Quash.ccp you are declaring the class once more.

You should instead define the methods. For instance:

```
Quash::Quash()
{
    heap = new Minheap();
    hash = new Hashtable();
}
```

On stackoverflow you should post minimal code showing the problem you incurred in (it's a good exercise shrinking the code while keeping the error) and I have the impression you didn't do that so I'm wondering what are you doing in order to prevent copy construction and assignment.